# Join of two tables as to get entire records

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am creating two tables .Table 1 has following schema

```
user_id       int            not null,autoincrement
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
rating        int
genre         varchar

user_Id    movie_Id    movie_name  user_name   rating  genre
1           1           Twister    Alex          6      Drama
2           !           Twister    Tim           1      Drama
(contd..)
```

while table 2 has following schema

```
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
genre         varchar

movie_Id   movie_Name    user_name   genre
2          Harry Porter  Alex        Fantay
3          Narnia        Alex        Fantasy
..
...(contd)
```

Now when I put a query to insert values it first checks whether a following username exist in first table .If true then it inserts into second table otherwise it inserts value as per schema into first table.In other words first table has unique usernames and unique user_Id while second contains many repeated usernames with movie they have seen

Now I want to join Table 1 and table 2 ,so that it contains all the colums of both table and a unique user_Id for user_name
and the movie they have seen and rating with genre

like for example

```
user_id   movie_Id  movie_name   user_name   rating  genre
1         1         Twister       Alex        6      Drama
1         2         Harry Porter  Alex        7      Fantasy
1         3         Narnia        Alex        6      Fantasy
2         1         Twister       Tim         1      Drama
```

...
and so on

Thanks

Comment: That's nice.  What's your question?

Comment: Hi Eggyal ,i am just a naive user of mysql so i just wanted to know how to combine both tables so as not to avoid any rows of two tables with unique user_Id for a specific user  .......... Thanks

Comment: "*so as not to avoid any rows of two tables with unique user_Id for a specific user*"?  I have absolutely no idea what that means.  But, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was going for Full JOIN AND NATURAL jOIN

Comment: Okay.  So what happened when you tried that?  Did you get an error?  If so, what did it say?  If not, how did the results differ from those you expected/desired?

Comment: hEY eGGYAL actually i am missing some of the row which i have just inserted.Like the last row ...Thanks

Comment: In your example output, you show ratings of 7 and 6 for Harry Potter and Narnia respectively; where do those ratings come from?

Comment: Hey eggyal That i am inserting...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select * from table2 inner join table1 on table2.user_id= table1.user_id
```

Comment: `table2.user_id` doesn't exist, according to the schema in the question.

Comment: here you go... its now updated.. `select * from table2 inner join table1 on table2.user_name = table1.user_name`

Comment: superb I was missing something Thanks Sameer and Eggyal

Comment: Hey one more issue Actually I want that join should be performed at runtime that is when I insert the data and run it should display the details which I entered before running.Is it possible??   Thanks

Comment: Hi Actually it doesn't take values from table 1...How can i have values from Table1

Comment: after saving the data, the page refreshes, your script should be able to fetch the new data as well.

Comment: Hi Sameer but actually it is not showing what i Have inserted in Table 1

Comment: I think you need to clean up your schema and create some relationships

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table2.* 
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table2.user name = table1.user_name
```

However, you should structure your database more like this:

```
table_users:
    user_id
    username
    ...

table_videos:
    video_id
    video_name
    video_genre
    ...

table_rentals
    record_id
    user_id 
    video_id
```

Then with a structure like that, you would use the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT table_users.user_id, table_users.username, table_videos.video_id, table_videos.video_name 
FROM table_videos 
INNER JOIN table_rentals 
     ON table_rentals.video_id = table_videos.video_id
INNER JOIN table_users 
     ON table_rentals.user_id = table_users.user_id
```

This is more normalized, and reduces duplicated data

Comment: Still not the expected answer